# setters and getters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn classes and setters and getters in JavaScript .. but my code isn't working .. it alerts undefined .. here is my code

```js
function Person () {
 name:"something"
 
Person.prototype = {
  get Name (){
   return name;
   },
   set Name (val){
    this.name = val;
    
   }
};
};
var person = new Person(); 
alert(person.name);
```

Comment: Is it really that hard to format and indent your code properly? What do you think `name:"something" does? Did you run your code through a linter?

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to set getters and setters in your example:

```
    function Person () {
        this.name = "something";
    }

    Person.prototype = {
        get Name() {
            return this.name;
        },
        set Name(val) {
            this.name = val;

        }
    };

    var person = new Person();
    person.Name = 'example';
    alert(person.name);
```

Comment: You might run into some issues setting the prototype like that because it overrides the constructor property.

Comment: You can add `constructor: Person` to prototype, but it is not the main idea of question :)

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

JS is based on prototypes, then u can define propertys:

```
function Person(){
   this._name = '';
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
            get: function(){
                return this._name;
            },
            set: function(value){
                this._name= value;
            },
            enumerable:true,
            configurable: true
});
```

Then u can set or get property "name"

```
var p = new Person()
p.name = 'Stackoverflow'
alert(p.name) // Stackoverflow
```

In ES6 u can use the keyword `class`, example:

```
class Person {
   constructor() {
     this.name = '';
  }
}
```